# How do I verify my express app has connected to a local instance of mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have a MEAN STACK App running locally ,which I created  by cloning the code ,after following this tutorial on Djamware. Link to the tutorial is https://www.djamware.com/post/58a91cdf80aca748640ce353/how-to-create-rest-api-easily-using-nodejs-expressjs-mongoosejs-and-mongodb

I run npm install and made sure my local version of mongodb is running.On running mongo its starts succesfully and the last line responds as follows

> I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017.

I then ran

> nodemon

on another terminal, which responds with

> connection successful
>   .

This is really where it gets confusing as when I run a post command via postman an instance of a product is created but the response of what is created only Shows as follows

> {
>          "_id": "5d19c75b326c0424d447135d",
>          "updated_at": "2019-07-01T08:42:03.721Z",
>         "__v": 0
>     }

what I expect is

> {
>          "_id": "5d19c75b326c0424d447135d",
>          "updated_at": "2019-07-01T08:42:03.721Z",
>         "__v": 0
>   "prod_name":"Sony PS 4","prod_desc":"Sony playstation 4","prod_price":580
>     }

as I also pass the prod_name and the other atrributes when creating the posts.

## Here is my server on app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var restful = require('node-restful');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var cors = require('cors');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var products = require('./routes/products');
var app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/product', {useNewUrlParser: true})
  .then(() =>  console.log('connection successful++'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({type:'application/vnd.api+json'}));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(cors());
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/api/v1/products', products);

var Category = app.resource = restful.model('category', mongoose.Schema({
  cat_name: String,
}))
.methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);

Category.register(app, '/category');

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json(err.message);
});

module.exports = app;
```

How do i make sure the objects are created correctly and verify im working on the right database instance.

Comment: what is your mongoose schema